# Thumbnails for videos in moodle

Tags: moodle

I was searching for the plugin of moodle that can create the thumbnails of videos that are stored in the repository. But I didn't find it.

I think this feature is not available yet. So is there any other alternative to perform this task in Moodle?

Right now I am working on moodle 2.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this plugin : https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?id=447

You will get the  documentation from here : http://knowledge.kaltura.com/

This may helps.

Comment: Hi gnuwings, 

Actually i have been checked kaltura. I installed it and tried to add the videos. But Videos more than one comes one by one. If i added 2 videos, it come at different 2 spaces. Its not seems like youtube. No thumbnails of videos on same platform.